# QProcess exe does not close if program finished

Tags: c++, qt, qprocess

My problem is that I am starting an executable in a QProcess like the following:

```
QProcess Work;
Work.start(program.exe);
```

This executable runs since it has been started in background and I can send requests to it. If I have finished I am closing the executable the following way:

```
Work.close();
```

But if I am looking at the Taskmanager the program.exe is running furthermore. I dont understand that behaviour because I thought the executable would been stopped if I close the Process.

Comment: With close you just finish communication with process, you are not killing it

Comment: What exactly *is* `program.exe` and how would you normally terminate it if running it at a command line?

Comment: program.exe is a program which starts a parallel thread to communicate with another IP. The executable does have a command terminate and I think I will use these command because I have found out that killing a process is very bad.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [void QProcess::terminate()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#terminate) or [void QProcess::kill()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#kill) for it.

`terminate()` - attempts to terminate the process.

`kill()` - kills process immediately.

Comment: And even terminate() or kill() work only for some programs not for all

Comment: in unix `kill()` send SIGKILL signal. This signal cannot be caught or ignored, and the receiving process cannot perform any clean-up upon receiving this signal. There are only a few rare cases, when SIGKILL is not working.

Comment: We don't know platform exactly

Comment: the platform is windows 7 and I have also tried kill() but i have heard it isn't a good idea to kill() or terminate() it directly because any file that has been opened can't be closed by the application if we kill it immediatelly.

Comment: On Windows, terminate() posts a WM_CLOSE message to all top-level windows of the process and then to the main thread of the process itself. So program **can** save file or prompt the user for confirmation if it necessary. But of course it should be implemented by the program developer.

Comment: according to the documentation, close() already uses kill: `void QProcess::close(): Closes all communication with the process and kills it. ... `

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar case, although I was working on linux embedded with QT 4.8. Not sure if this can help you, but since I can't put it in a comment, I have to make a separate answer.

Do you set a parent to your QProcess? In my case, I instantiated QProcess like this

```
QProcess *p = new QProcess;
```

and I could see in the running processes list that each time I instantiated a new QProcess, I got a new process that couldn't be closed by *close()*, *terminate()* or *kill()*. When I finally rewrote the code like this

```
QProcess *p = new QProcess(mainW); //mainW was my GUI class, which handled also the closing of the process
```

the problem solved itself, I didn't even need to call any function to close the process. In my case I was sure the processes I called were finishing, since almost all of them were audio files, so I could hear them finishing. The others were processes that my program waited to complete, so again I was sure they ended because my program wasn't stuck waiting for them,

Hope this can help, despite the different OS.